# How to capture the code or text of a key entry in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not familiar with iOS and Objective-C and I'm in need to find a way to capture a user's key entry into an input field.

I'm looking for something like [Android's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown`, where `KeyEvent.Callback.onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` provides an `int keyCode` and a `KeyEvent event`.

Or something like the `keydown` and `keyup` [event listeners in web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event), where the callback gets an `event` object which includes `event.code` and `event.keyCode`.

What's the simplest way to go about this in iOS?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main views used to capture text input on iOS: `UITextField` and `UITextView`. Each has a corresponding delegate to be notified of input changes.

### UITextFieldDelegate

`UITextField` has a delegate that conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate` you can use to get notified of input changes. Specifically, you will want to implement this method:

```
func textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) -> Bool
```

This method gets called each time there is an input change. The reason it provides a range of the characters is because a user can do something like cut or paste to change more than a character at a time. You can also see this method returns a boolean. You accept the text input by returning `true` and can reject the change by returning `false`.

### UITextViewDelegate

`UITextView`'s delegate conforms to `UITextViewDelegate`. You'll want to implement this method:

```
func textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:) -> Bool
```

This should work the same way as the method for `UITextFieldDelegate`.

If you're interested in just know that the text changed but don't need detailed information on what the exact change was, you can implement this method:

```
func textViewDidChange(_:)
```

Comment: Thanks, @AdamPro13. So I take it in both examples, when the user presses a single key (rather than pasting or replacing), then the `replacementString` and the `replacementText` parameters of the delegates are the text of the key entered, correct? So if the field already has a value of `lore` and the user presses the `m` key, the delegate gets `"m"` —as opposed to the full `"lorem"`. If you can please add that to the response I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.